# Scale PDF page sizes with screen using <object> tag

Tags: html, pdf

I am currently doing so like this:

```
<div class='embed-responsive' style='padding-bottom:150%'>
    <object data="../pdf/Invoice_file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="95%" height="800px" 
        style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />
        <p>Not supported by browser.</p>
    </object>
</div>
```

I looked at the other solutions on here but none of them worked. If possible I'd like to scale the PDF page size as the screen gets smaller. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your PDF of choice has a JS interface, you may find you can't achieve what you want. Why not - well I just opened a PDF file in Chrome and resides the browser window. The PDF page in view did not scale - so I conclude that Chrome's PDF viewer is coded to re-center the page on viewport dimension changes but not to scale the page.

I your PDF viewer of choice provides a JS interface, then you probably can do it.

Problems will no doubt occur if you cannot dictate the PDF viewer your users will choose.

Comment: Sorry to bring you down but you might as well know what you are biting off.